# How to create a private Play Store in a K3s cluster

Tags: android, google-play, cicd, k3s, dynamic-feature-module

I want to create an App Store in a K3s cluster. The idea is not to use Google Play Store, I want to do like a private Play Store using a K3s cluster to upload there my Android applications. How can I do it? The idea is that I don't want to use Google Play Store, but rather a private store to distribute (and if possible, automatically update) the applications I develop for the organization.

I am using GitLab CI/CD for security checks and the automation of application deployment. Can I automate the upload of the application to the private Play Store, or do I have to do it manually?

An extra feature is to use Dynamic Feature Modules of Google but in a private Play Store. First of all, I would like to create a private Play Store, but if I manage to do this, even better.

Thanks!

I have tried searching for online private repositories (like Google Drive) for uploading APKs, but both the application upload and download/update processes are manual. I want a more automated Play Store that updates the application automatically.

If it's possible to use Dynamic Feature Modules, that would be even better, but I'm fine with the alternative.

Thanks!